# Cannot Edit KVM Machine's XML; Failed to validate against schema

Tags: vim, kvm, xml, libvirt, virt-manager

**When trying to save XML changes in Vim this error occurs:**

error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng

Extra element devices in interleave
Element domain failed to validate content

---

Specifically, I'm trying to add the line  to the main XML document for my virtual machine (ran on virt-manager) named "Gaming" as part of the last step for this guide on passing through a graphics card; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTX10QlFJ6c.

I've already tried Vim's options of ignoring schema validation to save the file but the changes do not remain afterwards. Another option of forcing the save returns the same error. Everything I've read states that they get this error if their machine has spaces in it's name but never with a single capital letter. Asking here before I scrap the machine and try again with lowercase. If anyone has a workaround or an idea how to disable schema validation for the virtual machine to make this work please let me know, I'm a bit of a layperson but I'm learning.

EDIT 1: Trying to add what's in the yellow box to this part of the file
[image]

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>Gaming</name>
  <uuid>71d390ae-296e-4bff-b61c-0dacf9fe6515</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>12288000</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>12288000</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-6.2'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/Gaming_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv mode='custom'>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none' migratable='on'/>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/mnt/Data/VirtualMachine/Gaming.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <boot order='2'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x14'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x15'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0x16'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='8' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='8' port='0x17'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='9' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='9' port='0x18'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='10' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='10' port='0x19'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='11' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='11' port='0x1a'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='12' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='12' port='0x1b'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='13' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='13' port='0x1c'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='14' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='14' port='0x1d'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:7c:35:85'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='e1000e'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <sound model='ich9'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1b' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <audio id='1' type='spice'/>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='no'>
      <source>
      <rom file='/usr/share/vgabios/AMD.RX5700XT.8192.190616.rom'/>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x046d'/>
        <product id='0xc08b'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='4'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x0b05'/>
        <product id='0x1945'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='5'/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

As seen at [32:27](https://youtu.be/eTX10QlFJ6c?t=2007) in my guide video. Files in question are packaged and available for download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JSsz7pNwpz5fV_qsbUBs5dWnUnpBxI10/view?usp=share_link) **posting the other two files breaks the limits for posts**.
Should be noted that Gaming.xml is under root permissions on my system and won't open normally with gedit.

Comment: Since you've not shared the XML containing the issue it's not possible to confirm the issue or point out a possible mistake. However, are you absolutely and totally sure that what you're trying to do is permitted by the intended target schema? (Not necessarily the schema recognised by `vim`, although I'd hope that was the right one.)

Comment: If you update your question to show the change you're trying to make, we'll be in a better position to help you out.

Comment: perhaps you're putting in the wrong section, like numpty almost did on the video

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, wasn't expecting them. I included the files now, including the schema. I'm not sure that rom is accepted by it but from what my pea brain divines from the code is that it probably is. I don't think I have it in the wrong spot. Thanks again!

Comment: Added the raw text of Gaming.xml

Comment: The text XML you've included validates against [`domain.xsd`](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/vmnetx/blob/master/schema/domain.xsd), described as "_libvirt 0.9.8 domain XML schema, translated to XML Schema_"

Comment: Downloading the ZIP you've linked, which includes `domain.rng`, both the XML file in that ZIP and the modified one posted here in the question validate correctly (`xmlstarlet validate --relaxng domain.rng gaming.xml`). What's the problem?